# Changed local host wordpress site URL, can't log in

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been building my website offline using MAMP. I have my domain hosted on Bluehost and wanted to migrate my offline website onto Bluehost's servers. I changed my "Wordpress Address (URL)" and my "Site address (URL)" to the the domain name currently on Bluehost. Now I cannot access my original site files as my log in credentials are not accepted anymore. I've tried editing the wp-config and functions to change the URLs back but then I get a redirect error. Please help.

TLDR: How do I change my Wordpress Address and Site Address back to my local URL without being able to log in to my dashboard?

Comment: can you post here error logs?

Comment: Please see edit, thanks

Comment: my friend there are syntax error in wp-config.php on line 91.

Comment: ya, that's been taken care of and still the problem persists. it was just a typo, nothing to do with the root problem

Answer (score 0):

> How do I change my Wordpress Address and Site Address back to my local URL without being about to log in to my dashboard?

These are stored in the database, table `wp-options` (in case u use the `wp_` prefix).

Comment: What do I do in options.php to fix this?

Comment: These setting are stored in the database, not in a PHP file. Connect to your DB (I recommend Adminner, or PHPMyAdmin), find the wp-options table and there will be your options.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is how to fix it:

1- open http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

2- click on your database's name

3- click on SQL "so that you can write a SQL query"

4- execute this :

```
UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value = 'https://localhost/NAME OF YOUR WEBSITE FOLDER'
WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' OR option_name = 'home
```

the url you changed are stored in the database, in the table `wp-options` by default, change the wp_ if you modified it to something else.